# AWS error "EC2Client is 'friend'" - bug in SDK for .NET?

Tags: vb.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to write a program in vb.net which uses AWS's Web Service to change the permissions for a security group in EC2. 
I have installed the AWS SDK for .Net.

I found an example of how to do this in C# on http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/sdk-net/latest/aws-sdk-net-dg.pdf (page 39).

I have managed to translate the code into vb, but I am getting an error concerning the 2nd of the following two lines:

```
Dim ec2Client As New AmazonEC2Client(credentials, config)
 Dim ingressResponse As AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressResponse = ec2Client.AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress(ingressRequest)
```

The error Visual Studio gives for this second line is:

```
Amazon.EC2.AmazonEC2Client.Friend Function AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress(request As Amazon.EC2.Model.AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest) As Amazon.EC2.Model.AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressResponse' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.
```

I have read everything I can find on the topic and have posted this on the AWS forum but nothing is helping me.

All other AWS references within Visual Studio seem fine, so I am beginning to wonder whether this is a bug in the SDK for .NET.

I am desperate for help as I cannot call the AWS web-service without this line.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is a bug; however, I have found a way to get around it by using AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress*Async* instead of AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress:

```
             Dim ec2Client As New AmazonEC2Client(credentials, config)
            Dim ingressResponse As System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressResponse) = ec2Client.AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressAsync(ingressRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
Dim ingressResponse As AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressResponse() = ec2Client.AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress(ingressRequest)
```

You are storing the response of `AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress` in a **function()** rather than a variable.

Change `AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressResponse()` into `AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressResponse`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I will edit the question. However, even when I change that it gives me the same error. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not caused by a bug in the SDK. The reason you are getting the error about the method being defined as Friend is that you have to use the Async version of the method call. Not obvious, I know, but that means that you have to put the call in a Function that is defined as Async with a return type of Task.

Then, when you call the method, you need to use the following:

```
Dim ec2Client As New AmazonEC2Client(credentials, config)
Dim ingressResponse As AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressResponse = Await ec2Client.AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress(ingressRequest)
```

By using the Await modifier, you actually get a response object as the return value from the method call.